# MVC 1 submit button with multiple actions

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am creating a real estate application and I am confused over how to show the buy and rent urls.

I have a page with 2 radio buttons for buy and rent.

When a user clicks on the search button I would like to call a different action on my controller based on the radio button selection and navigate to that url.

eg if the user clicks on the buy radio button and clicks search the action will be buy and the url will be /buy/properties

if the user clicks on the rent radio button and clicks search the action will be rent and the url will be /rent/properties

I only want one submit button which is called search and it calling different actions based on the radio button selection.

I am not sure how to perform this task?

Comment: You need to use javascript/jquery to build the url based on the selected radio button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As an alternative to Javascript, you could simply post your form to a controller action and redirect from there.

```
public ActionResult ActionName(PurchaseType purchaseType)
{
  if (purchaseType == PurchaseType.Rent)
    return RedirectToAction("Rent", "Index");
  else
    return RedirectToAction("Buy", "Index");
}
```

Comment: This answer sent me in the right direction, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose your button I html is like:

```
<input type="button" id="btnSubmit" value="Search" />
```

And radio buttons will be like:

```
<input type="radio" name="trade" value="Buy">Buy</input>
<input type="radio" name="trade" value="Rent">Rent</input>
```

in Jquery U will be writing

```
$("#btnSubmit").click(function(){
var checkedValue=$('input:radio[name=trade]:checked').val();
var URL = //Based on the checkedValue, you can hit the desired URL string here.
$.get(URL, function(data) {

}); 
}

});
```

Answer (score 0):

If You Want To Post Form You Can Use This.
   
Html Code:

```
<form  action="" method="post" id="MyForm">
       <label>
          <input type="radio" name="StateType" value="Buy" />
           Buy
        </label>
        <label>
          <input type="radio" name="StateType" value="Rent" />
           Rent
        </label>

        <input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="redirect()" />

</form>
```

JQuery Code:

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script>
    function redirect() {
        if ($("#MyForm").valid()) {
            // if form isValid
            var url = "";
            var urlBuy = "@Url.Action("Buy","Home")";
            var urlRent = "@Url.Action("Rent","Home")";

            var selectedRadio = $("input[name='StateType']:checked").val();

            if (selectedRadio == "Buy") {
                url = urlBuy;
            } else {
                url = urlRent;
            }

            var frm = $(event.target).closest("form");
            frm.attr("action", url);
            frm.submit();
        }
    }
</script>
```

Good Luck